# Perl character searching in a string with patterns

Tags: perl

Is there a built in function on which determines if a character is present in a string. Also how can you determine if a value is a string or a number.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built in function in perl called the index function also use pattern matching like

to use index : index($stringvariable,"char to search");
to determine if a number use the code m/\d/
if you want to determine if a value is a string use m/\D/
Use pattern matching techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Perl's scalars are a string and a number *at the same time*. To test whether a scalar can be used as a number without any warnings:

```
use Scalar::Util qw/looks_like_number/;

my $variable = ...;
if (not defined $variable) {
    # it is not usable as either a number or a string, as it is "undef"
}
elsif (looks_like_number $variable) {
    # it is a number, but can also be used as a string
}
else {
    # you can use it as a string
}
```

Actually, the story is a bit more complex with objects which may or may not be usable as numbers or strings. Furthermore, `looks_like_number` can return a true value for `Infinity` and `NaN` (not a number), which may not be what you consider to be a number.

---

To test whether a string contains some substring, you can use regexes or the `index` function:

```
my $haystack = "foo";
my $needle   = "o";
if (0 <= index $haystack, $needle) {
    # the $haystack contains the $needle
}
```

Some people prefer the equivalent test `-1 != index ...` instead.